# How to delete eos account?

Tags: accounts

I have an existing account named aaa, and then i create a new account named bbb with aaa. It costs several eos tokens for ram/cpu/net stake.
Is there a way to delete account bbb, and reclaim ram/cpu/net staked eos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t delete account but you could undelegate all staked EOS and effectively leave that account inactive.

Comment: What about RAM? I can't sell all the account's RAM because the account itself takes RAM on the blockchain.

Answer (score 5):

After some research, account cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

when someone create an account it will be propagated to all BPs and then be stored on blockchain comprising with 2 public keys.

In EOS eco-system user has only one way to transfer EOS to each other via Account Name so logically and technically it can't be deleted.